# What is the difference between Ratschlag and Vorschlag?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verb-usage

What is the difference between these two?

And one more thing, would empfehlen and vorschlagen be synonyms? what about beraten?

**Beraten** and **vorschlagen** appear to be an advise or suggestion, **empfehlen** and **vorschlagen** appear to be also a suggestion or recommendation, so I assume there is a difference between all of them but I don't quite understand this difference.
Also, in Duden braten appears as jemandem einen Rat geben, so what would be the difference also between Rat geben and beraten? I've read that Beraten is quite stronger than Rat geben, but this difference is yet not so clear to me.

Comment: What did your dictionary say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ratschlag = advice. A recommendation given to someone who presumably knows less about something than you do, e.g. "Oh, I wouldn't buy remoulds if I were you."

Vorschlag = suggestion. An option offered to someone else with no implication that it is better than anything else, it might just fit better into your calendar, e.g. "How about Thursday night?"